# Problema ao executar Ionic --device

Tags: ionic2

Executei o comando `ionic cordova run android --device` porém, a execução parou na aqui:

```
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild
UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
UP-TO-DATE

:prepareDebugDependencies

:compileDebugAidl
UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig
UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugResValues
UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources
```

E não sai mais, alguém tem alguma ideia do motivo ?

Comment: Se vc executar "ionic serve" ele roda sem problemas?

Comment: Sim, roda sem problemas.  @AndréVicente, porem eu nao tinha executado o cmd como Administrador, feito isso funcionou.